# How to highlight code in knitr chunk output

Tags: r, knitr

Rmarkdown chunks by default display the input code block and the output block. The code block is highlighted by default and the output verbatim text is usually not. If I am running some code that generates more code, is it possible to show code highlighting in the output block?

For example, this chunk executes R code

````
```{r,echo=FALSE}
paste0("cp -R ",getwd(),"/* ./dir")
```
````

to generate valid shell code as the output.

```
"cp -R /home/user/work/* ./dir"
```

Can this output be code highlighted for shell script? The output code does not have to be evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the chunk option `class.output` and specify the language name, e.g.

````
```{r, class.output='sh', comment=''}
cat('ls -l "$HOME"')  # sh for shell scripts
```
````